# Splitsample in Stata 16: How to create samples based on varying proportions saved in a variable?

Tags: stata, sampling, experimental-design

**Datastructure:** I use panel data in which an observation represents a certain individual in a given year (2015-2021). Only observations are included of individuals who are between the 15 and 25 years old. There are 2857 observations of 1373 individuals in total.

**Goal:** The goal is to investigate the effect of a policy change in 2018. In doing so, I designed a quasi-experimental design in which there are two controlgroups and a treatmentgroup defined in terms of their age:

- Controlgroup A: individuals 15-17 years old
- Treatmentgroup: individuals 18-22 years old
- Controlgroup B: individuals 23-25 years old

**Dividing individuals into treatment and controlgroups based on varying chance:**
due to methodological reasons, *individuals selected in a controlgroup may not become part of the treatment group* (due to aging over time) and vice versa. Therefore I am confronted with the question how to select the right individuals (given their *age* and the *year*) for the treatment and controlgroups.
To ensure that every year has observations of individuals in all ages, I came up with the following design (see picture).
There are 17 theoretically possible individuals in my data (vertical as in the picture) who age over 7 years (2015-2021). I would like to sample the individuals into the treatment and controlgroups based on the chances mentioned in the table beneath to ensure all ages are represented in all years.

[image]

**Programming**
I constructed a variable (1-17) indicating what number an individual represents (like the vertical numbers in the table above)

```
gen individualnumber=(age-year)+2007
```

I constructed three variables indicating the chances of being in controlgroup A, B or treatment in the following way:

```
 gen Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517=0
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517=1 if individualnumber==1 | individualnumber==2 | individualnumber==3
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517=0.75 if individualnumber==4
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517=0.60 if individualnumber==5
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517=0.50 if individualnumber==6
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517=0.43 if individualnumber==7
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517=0.29 if individualnumber==8
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517=0.14 if individualnumber==9

gen Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325=0
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325=1 if individualnumber==15 | individualnumber==16 | individualnumber==17
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325=0.75 if individualnumber==14
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325=0.60 if individualnumber==13
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325=0.50 if individualnumber==12
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325=0.43 if individualnumber==11
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325=0.29 if individualnumber==10
replace Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325=0.14 if individualnumber==9

gen Chanceofbeingtreated=1-(Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517+Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325)
```

After that I wanted to construct the samples...

```
splitsample, generate(treatedornot) split(Chanceofbeingcontrol_1517 Chanceofbeingtreated Chanceofbeingcontrol_2325) cluster(individualnumber) rround show
```

...but I received an error since only a numlist might be used in the split(numlist) subcommand.

**Question:** How to construct the samples or overcome this error in an efficient way?

---

**Example**: An individuals (number 7 in the table) who is 15 years old in 2015 (controlgroup 1 age), will be 18 years old in 2018 (which is the treatment age). But this individual may not be part of both the treatment and controlgroup and should therefore be a member of one of the two. Therefore I want to draw three random samples among all number 7 individuals.
Let's state there are 100 individuals like individual 7 in the table.

- Sample 1 is controlgroup A and individual 7 will occur 43 times in this sample
- Sample 2 is the treatment group so individual 7 occurs 57 times in this sample
- While individual 7 will not occur in sample 3 since this person is never older than 22 during 2015-2021.

---

Answer (score 1):

What's common for all people who were 9 in 2015, 10 in 2016, 11 in 2017 is that they were born 2006. And all who were 10 in 2015 was born 2005. So instead of a variable `individualnumber` that can be hard to understand for someone who reads your code, why don't you create a variable called `birthyear`. That will make it easier to explain your design to your peers.

Regardless of what you call the variable or what the value it contains represent, I would solve it something like this. You will probably need to tweak this code. Provide a replicable subset of your data (see the command `dataex`) if you want a replicable answer.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte id int year double age
1 2017 15
1 2017 15
2 2017 15
2 2017 15
3 2017 15
3 2017 15
4 2017 15
4 2017 15
5 2015 12
5 2015 12
end

* Create the var that will display the 
gen birthyear = year-age

    preserve

    * Collapse year-person level data to person level so 
    * that each individual only get one treatment status.
    * You must have an individual id number for this
    * Get standard deviation to test that data is good and the birthyear
    * is identical for each individual across the panel data set
    collapse (mean) birthyear (sd) bysd=birthyear, by(id)

    * Test that birthyear is same across all indivudals - this is not needed,
    * but good data quality assurance test. Then drop the var as it is not needed
    assert bysd == 0
    drop bysd

    * Set seed to make replicable. Replace this seed when you have tested this
    * script using a new random seed. For example from here:
    * https://www.random.org/integers/?num=1&min=100000&max=999999&col=5&base=10&format=html&rnd=new
    set seed 123456

    *Generate a random number based on the seed
    gen random_draw = runiform()

    * For each birthyear, get the rank of the random number divided by the number
    * of individuals in each birthyear
    sort birthyear random_draw
    by birthyear : gen percent_rank = _n/_N

    *Initiate treatmen variable
    gen tmt_status = .
    label define tmt_status 0 "Treated" 1 "ControlA" 2 "ControlB"

    *Assign birthyear 2006-2004 that are all the same
    replace tmt_status = 1 if birthyear == 2006
    replace tmt_status = 1 if birthyear == 2005
    replace tmt_status = 1 if birthyear == 2004

    *Assign birthyear 2003
    replace tmt_status = 0 if birthyear == 2003 & percent_rank <= .25
    replace tmt_status = 1 if birthyear == 2003 & percent_rank >  .25

    *Assign birthyear 2002
    replace tmt_status = 0 if birthyear == 2002 & percent_rank <= .40
    replace tmt_status = 1 if birthyear == 2002 & percent_rank >  .40

    *Fill in birthyear 2001-1999

    *Assign year 1998
    replace tmt_status = 0 if birthyear == 1998 & percent_rank <= .72
    replace tmt_status = 1 if birthyear == 1998 & percent_rank >  .72 & percent_rank <= .86
    replace tmt_status = 2 if birthyear == 1998 & percent_rank >  .86

    *Fill in birthyear 1997-1990

    * Do some tabulates etc to convince yourself the randomization is as expected

    * Save tempfile of data to be merged to later
    * (Consider saving this as a master data set https://worldbank.github.io/dime-data-handbook/measurement.html#constructing-master-data-sets)
    tempfile assignment_results
    save `assignment_results'
    
restore

merge m:1 id using `assignment_results'
```

This code can be made more concise using loop, but random assignment is so important as I personally always go for clarity over conciseness when doing this.

This is not answering specifically about `splitsample`, but it addresses what you are trying to do. You will have to decide how you want to do with groups that does not have a size that can be split into the exact ratio you prefer.